# Adding a marketo form to github

Tags: javascript, forms, embed, marketo

I need to embed a marketo form onto a github page, essentially host it there, then iframe it into  another piece of software I'm using. The iframing in afterwards is striaght forward as the software does that. But I cant work out how to actually embed it on github.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Marketo form
2. Grab the form embed code
3. Grab the munchkin tracking code too. Not 100% essential but needed if you want web page tracking on the Github page the form will live on.
4. Drop code in a Div section.
5. From my code example you could replace 132 (with your actual form ID)
6. And replace 111-AAA-111 wit your Munchkin ID.

Example

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page_1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Test form. Embedded</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <script src="//app-abj.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
            <form id="mktoForm_123"></form>
            <script>MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-abj.marketo.com", "111-AAA-111", 123);</script>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer: text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```